# Compute probability of arrival times of two independent Poisson processes

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I'm solving a problem of two independent Poisson processes $N^1_t \text{ and } N^2_t$. An some point I have to compute the probability that the third arrival of the second process be less than the first arrival of the first process i.e.:
$$P\left[ S^2_3< S^1_1 \right]$$
Where $S_n$ is the arrival time of the nth event.

What I've done:
$$P\left[ S^2_3< S^1_1 \right]= \int_0^\infty P\left[ S^2_3< S^1_1| S^1_1=x\right] P\left[ S^1_1=x\right]dx$$
$$= \int_0^\infty P\left[S^2_3< x\right] P\left[ S^1_1=x\right] dx$$
$$= \int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^{x}P\left[S^2_3= u\right]du \right) P\left[ S^1_1=x\right] dx$$
And due to $S_n \sim gamma(n,\delta)$ the integral could be solved by using the PDF, however it is a long way.

Is there an easy  way to compute this probability?

Comment: Your integral becomes zero due to $P[S_1^1=x]=0$ for all $x$. You need to use the exponential pdf. In other words, you have not correctly used the law of total probability in integral form. Aside: You could alternatively condition on $S_3^2=x$.

Comment: You can also think sequentially about “racing exponentials.” Team 2 wins 3 times in a row and then Team 1 wins.

Comment: @Michael Or perhaps Team 2 wins 3 times in a row, and then you do not care.  So if they are i.i.d. then $\frac1{2^3}$

Comment: @Henry : Ah yes, you do not care what happens after team 2 wins 3 times in a row. Thanks.